# Error: ORA-00969: missing ON keyword - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g XE database and Oracle SQL developer to execute SQL statements.
I have this SQL statement which is giving me the above compiler error when executing it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER "STD"."TRG_STUDENT"
BEFORE INSERT,DELETE
ON STUDENT
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserting !!');
  END IF;
  IF DELETING THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Deleting !!');
  END IF;
END;
```

I tried some variations but I used to get other errors.
I placed the `ON STUDENT` just before the `BEFORE INSERT,DELETE` line and I get this error:

```
Error: ORA-04071: missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE
```

More about Create Trigger syntax: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm

Comment: It complied. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE` instead of `BEFORE INSERT, DELETE`. Refer [coding trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm) for more in detail.

Comment: How did I miss that? Thank you :)